# Update dataframe values based on comparison with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframe that need to be compare and update the dataframe 1 values based on the dataframe 2 values.

dataframe1

```
DU ID   Part Number        Qty   Unit
102     00334567            1       PCS 
102     00334567            2       PCS
102     RRWQTDFG            3       PCS
102     3456DDHE            4       PCS
102     DF033WW2            2       PCS
```

dataframe 2 is a list with unique Part Number and actual quantity.
dataframe2

```
DU ID   Part Number   Actual Qty   Unit
102     00334567            10      PCS 
102     RRWQTDFG            3       PCS
102     3456DDHE            7       PCS
102     DF033WW2            0       PCS
```

i would like to replace the dataframe1 values with the dataframe2 values

as per below example:
part number 00334567 has a quantity of 3 in dataframe 1 but the actual quantity is 10, so i will need to update the qty of the 2nd 00334567 with the value of 9 to match the actual quantity in dataframe 2

the output looks like this

```
DU ID   Part Number   Actual Qty   Unit
102     00334567            1       PCS 
102     00334567            9       PCS
102     RRWQTDFG            3       PCS
102     3456DDHE            7       PCS
102     DF033WW2            0       PCS
```

what i've tried to do now is like this.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(r'\path\to_df1_excel', 'sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(r'\path\to_df2_excel', 'sheet1')
```

group by to get the total quantity

```
cc_group = df1.groupby(['DU ID', 'Part Number'])['Qty'].sum().reset_index(name='cc_qty')
mr_group = df2.groupby(['DU ID', 'Part Number'])['Actual Qty'].sum().reset_index(name='mr_qty')
```

merge to compare both quantity and find difference

```
output = cc_group.merge(mr_group, on=['DU ID', 'Part Number'], how='outer').query('cc_qty != mr_qty').fillna(0)
```

now i am stuck on how to update dataframe1 with the Actual Qty (mr_qty from output). Need some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to change the quantity of `d1` with the (actual) quantity of `df2`. I think there is a more straightforward way to do so than what you are doing. Have a look:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'DU ID':[102, 102, 102, 102, 102], 
                   'Part Number':['00334567', '00334567', 'RRWQTDFG', '3456DDHE', 'DF033WW2'], 
                   'Qty':[1, 2, 3, 4, 2],
                   'Unit':['PCS', 'PCS', 'PCS', 'PCS', 'PCS']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'DU ID':[102, 102, 102, 102], 
                   'Part Number':['00334567', 'RRWQTDFG', '3456DDHE', 'DF033WW2'], 
                   'Actual_Qty':[10, 3, 7, 0],
                   'Unit':['PCS', 'PCS', 'PCS', 'PCS']})
```

Now you merge the two dataframes:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=['Part Number', 'DU ID', 'Unit'])

   DU ID Part Number  Qty Unit  Actual_Qty
0    102    00334567    1  PCS          10
1    102    00334567    2  PCS          10
2    102    RRWQTDFG    3  PCS           3
3    102    3456DDHE    4  PCS           7
4    102    DF033WW2    2  PCS           0
```

You can either stop here if you are okay with having both quantity columns or you clean up:

```
df1 = df1[['DU ID', 'Part Number', 'Actual_Qty', 'Unit']]
df1.columns = ['DU ID', 'Part Number', 'Qty', 'Unit']

   DU ID Part Number  Qty Unit
0    102    00334567   10  PCS
1    102    00334567   10  PCS
2    102    RRWQTDFG    3  PCS
3    102    3456DDHE    7  PCS
4    102    DF033WW2    0  PCS
```

**Edit**: Apperently I misunderstood. Here is what you want (`df1` and `df2` same as before):

```
index_df = df1.reset_index().groupby(by='Part Number').last().reset_index()[['Part Number', 'index']]

quantities = pd.merge(df1.groupby(by='Part Number')['Qty'].sum().reset_index(), df2, on='Part Number')

quantities['missing_qty'] = quantities.Actual_Qty - quantities.Qty
quantities = quantities[['Part Number', 'missing_qty']]

new_info = pd.merge(index_df, quantities, on='Part Number')
new_info.set_index('index', inplace=True)

df1.loc[new_info.index, 'Qty'] = df1.loc[new_info.index, 'Qty'] + new_info['missing_qty']

   DU ID Part Number  Qty Unit
0    102    00334567    1  PCS
1    102    00334567    9  PCS
2    102    RRWQTDFG    3  PCS
3    102    3456DDHE    7  PCS
4    102    DF033WW2    0  PCS
```

Comment: Close, but the output for qty should be the total sum of the same part number qty in the same du id. Your current 00334567 total sum is 30 instead of 10.

Comment: @ReverseEngineer I think I got what you want now, have a look at the edit. Note that my solution adjusts the last number. Therefore, some quantities might become negative if the actual quantity is lower than the quantity and the last entry is sufficiently small.

Comment: By the way, do you mind explaining your method step by step?